# Differentiate the Function: $g(u)=\ln\left(\frac{\ln\ u}{1+\ln\ (2u)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$g(u)=\ln\left(\frac{\ln\ u}{1+\ln\ (2u)}\right)$$

$$=\ln\ (\ln\ u)-\ln(1+\ln\ (2u))$$

This is the part where I get a little confused. Keep in mind I am using this formula $$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln g(x)]=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

and this one also $$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln\ x]=\frac{1}{x}$$ thus,

$$=\frac{1}{\ln\ u} - \frac{(1+ \ln (2u)\cdot (2)}{1?\ln\ (2u)\cdot (2u)}$$

Am I right?

Comment: You have no answer sheet?)
Say me name of book, i`ll try to find it to you

Comment: These are the even number problems for Essential Calculus James Stewart second edition.

Comment: is it $g(y)$? or $g(u)$?

Comment: http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780495014423-stewart-essential-calculus/
Isnt it, if no you can found out your book there

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner it is g(u).

Comment: Музаффар Шакаров - Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you seem to make a mistake.

As you wrote, using
$$(\ln(f(u)))'=\frac{f'(u)}{f(u)}\tag1$$
we have $$(\ln(\ln(u))-\ln (1+\ln(2u)))'=\frac{(\ln(u))'}{\ln(u)}-\frac{(1+\ln(2u))'}{1+\ln(2u)}$$
Here, use $(1)$ again.

Comment: Where did the (ln(lnu)) go? Should that be in the denominator?

Comment: @SunnyBlack: Note that $(\ln(f(u)))'=\frac{f'(u)}{f(u)}$. Here, if $f(u)=\ln(u)$, then we have $(\ln(\ln(u)))'=\frac{(\ln(u))'}{\ln(u)}$.